# how to create a material design header for the app using polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0

```
<app-header fixed condenses effects="waterfall">
<app-toolbar>
  <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
  <div title>My Menu</div>
  <paper-icon-button icon="shopping-cart"></paper-icon-button>
</app-toolbar>
```

The above code displays only My menu in a blank white page. How to create a app header with material design? where should i change the code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [paper-elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements) in the polymer catalog? These are designed to follow the material design specifications. There is a `paper-header-panel` element and a `paper-toolbar` element which will display as you expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

You should check polymer [app-elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=app-elements) 
It provides you application layout including drawer, main content (header, footer)

```html
<app-drawer-layout>
 <app-drawer>
    <!-- drawer-content -->
 </app-drawer>
 <app-header-layout>
  <app-header>
    <app-toolbar>
        <div title>App name</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>
    <!-- main content -->
  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```